# How can I change the color of the drawer icons?

Tags: android, flutter

How can I change the color of the drawer icons ? it is currently white, and I want it in black.

```
drawer: new Drawer(
    child: new ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            accountName: Text('test'),
            accountEmail: Text('test'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a new style for your icon `style.xml` file:

```
<style name="DrawerIconStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
       <item name="spinBars">true</item>
       <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

and add it to your page theme (in same file):

```
<style name="Your.Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    ...

    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerIconStyle</item>

    ...
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    drawer: new Drawer(),
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text("Navigation Drawer"),
      iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.green),
    ),
  );
}
```

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: I don't want to change UserAccountsDrawerHeader I want to change that with the three dashes